# How would I make setInterval run when out of focus?

Tags: javascript, html

In my current website I'm trying to make a cookie clicker type game... But when I run the collector for currency per second it slows down when I switch tabs...

Here is the script:

```
setInterval(ppsCollector,16.6666666667);
function ppsCollector() {
  var ppf = pps / 60;
  pounds += ppf;
  document.getElementById("poundCount").innerHTML = metricAbbreviate(pounds);
  document.getElementById("pps").innerHTML = metricAbbreviate(pps);
}
```

Is there any way to run this at the same rate when out of focus?

Thanks for all help in advance. :)

Comment: Can you indicate what browser/device/OS you are running into this issue with?

Comment: I'm using Firefox. However it stops on all browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research on this issue it looks like browsers forcible increase the interval of background tabs in order to prevent the machine from slowing down if they have a bunch of tabs open.  However there are some workarounds that you can implement (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927432/1640090) for complete list).

I recommend that you take a look at [HTML5 Web Workers](https://robertnyman.com/2010/03/25/using-html5-web-workers-to-have-background-computational-power/).  The only con is that they cannot access the DOM directly so you are going to need to utilize the `PostMessage` method to send a message back to the parent JavaScript in order to update the desired elements.